# How to do login authentication and session managemnt for any user in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

What are the best and easy options to setup login authentication and session management in spring mvc? I was reading some examples, but in almost all cases I see exact username , password they are putting in configuration file. I'm very much confused. Also spring session management article was not much help for me.
Any link, tutorial or example will be really helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Too big to cover it here, but my video tutorial "Spring Framework 4 Tutorial: Practical, Rapid, Intuitive" has a user module depicting it. It's the second one here: http://www.naturalprogrammer.com/tutorials/

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read about [spring security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/)   first and then [session management](http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-security/session-management-in-spring-security).

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.